# Check permission does not give all group names

Tags: permissions

I have added a user to 3 different SharePoint groups and when i checked permission in site permission/check permission, it showed only one result.
Is there any settings to update it ?

Comment: In the other 2 groups, how is the user added, via AD group or listed explicitly?

Comment: In all groups it is added similarly .
In Setting/people and group /add user to group